# Unable to retrieve user info through facebook api or FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am building an app in which I need to read education and work history of all people(if it is not hidden by privacy settings) in a facebook group(public group). People in the group need not necessarily be friends of the user logged in to my app.

I know how to get the facebook IDs of all people who are part of the group but am unable to retrieve the education/work history of some people even though it is made visible to everyone on facebook.

For eg: when I visited the profile page of a person on the group(who is not my friend), I was able to see his eduaction/work info. However, when I query through rest API or graph API or FQL, I get a null value!!

I have tried the following:

1) https://graph.facebook.com/UID
 I tried the above by a generating an access token too, still got only a null value

2) https://api.facebook.com/method/users.getInfo?uids=UID&fields=education_history

3) https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20education_history%20from%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20UID

This is the JSON response I get:
[
  {
    "education_history": null
  }
]

I would greatly appreciate for any help on how I can read this information.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It doesn't make sense that the user can specifically grant the permission ('friends_education_history') but then the app can't access that info. We need clarification on this issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can not do this because of privacy settings of the other users and the restrictions of facebook.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that the privacy settings were such that any user in facebook could read that person's education/work info(after logging in to facebook, I could read it and I was not that person's friend). Me, as a user logged into facebook, can read that info. But me, as an application, is not able to read that info. This is what the problem is all about... And before you ask me to request permissions from that user, read my comments to the previous answer.

Comment: All API calls and data availability are subject to specific application permissions, given by a user. If a user (a member of your group) does not authorize your application to get information about himself, your application will get empty results. You see this information on facebook, because they have this permission of the user. Again, there is no way to claim data you are not allowed to get.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request user_education_history and friends_education_history permitions before you read any education info. Look at [example](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#requesting-extended-permissions) from Facebook.

Comment: No, these permissions will only enable me to read the logged in user's and his friends education_history. As I've mentioned in my question, the people in the group are not friends with the logged in user. So, these permissions don't solve the problem. It is like this- the user selects a particular public group and the app shows the education history of all members of the group. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If this user not allow to read his info to others, You will not able to read his info anyway.

If he shares own info to everyone, the permissions Lex wrote whould be anougth to get this info, dont matter logged he or not, friend or not.

In case of application, when user add it on his page, he gives also the permissions to application to read his general info, so you can get application access_token with nessesary permissions and read any info you need about your application members.